# 2006 Honda Ridgeline timing

Tags: honda, cam-timing, ridgeline

The cam moved while trying to get the belt on but when I try and put it back on the timing mark, it must be on a lobe and it keeps wanting to jump backwards about 5 lobes or forwards 5 lobes, this is the back cam, the front and crank are line up,

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question here? Are you wondering what you're doing wrong? Or how to get it together? You aren't specifically stating what you're wanting to know, so any answer I would give you would be a stab in the dark. This is the 3.5L V6, correct?

Comment: Also, [this article](https://acurazine.com/how-tos/a/acura-tl-2004-2008-how-to-replace-timing-belt-water-pump-and-thermostat-423929) I wrote for a business called Internet Brands (not a promotion, just being honest) may be of help. It is for the 2004-2008 Acura TL, but it's the same basic engine and the process should be the same. Make sure you're using the correct alignment mark on the rear camshaft gear.